# Woocommerce custom new template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As woocommerce provides capability to override their templates by copying templates to our themes/child-theme in order to do custom modification in the cart and other template pages,

What I need to know is for e.g. consider I've three different pages:

```
 1. Shop (default woocommerce page)
 2. Sales Items  (custom page)
 3. New Arrivals  (custom page)
```

and on custom pages I want to show products list and I want them to work same as shop page with woocommerce sorting functionality, even if I've to use a woocommerce filter plugin it should also work same on custom pages as it works for shop page as modifying the plugin is not what I want and not all plugin can be modified by putting them in theme. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a child theme.

"A child theme is a layer that you put on top of the parent theme to make alterations without having to develop a new theme from scratch"

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I'm talking about making custom new template in theme in woocommerce templates and use it show different products for e.g. archive-product-sales.php so it should only show sale items and should inherit all functions that woocommerce shop page uses, like sorting and other functionalities.

Comment: What is your exact question then? Creating a specific template for item/archive/category is a matter of creating a new file. In that file, you will have access to wp loop and woocommerce API. Use that to create whatever functionality you like. An easier way forward would be to duplicate an existing template and modify it to your needs.

Comment: please check my question clearly what I've mentioned is (in short terms), can we create custom woo template like shop page uses archive-product.php , so I want to show sale items in new page for e.g. archive-saleproducts.php so if I'm using any woocommerce plugin then like it works on shop page it should work on my new custom template as well, if that is possible or not, as I've tried from my end still don't get to make it work